# How to set the time picker range within single day schedule

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, timepicker

I need to validate the time picker based on match starting

For Example :
     user can conduct 3 matches today:

```
      1. match 1 start at 09:00 to 12:00 (atleast 3 hours needed to finish a match).
      2. match 2 start at 12:30 to 16:00 (each and every match having 30 mins gap).
      3. match 3 start at 16:30 to 20:00
```

Yes i need to validate like this based on the number matches i append time picker in dialog box please some one help me friends. . . .

My Code :

http://jsbin.com/mexesuwo/2/edit

Comment: I think your example in JSBin is not working. Your question is not very clear either. If I were an user of your solution, how would I interact with it? What information do I need to enter/select?